# Water not flowing on automatic wheat farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making an automatic wheat farm on my computer, and when I want the water to flow, this happens: [image] I have tried so many ways to try and fix it, but it wouldn't work. (I'm using Minecraft 1.10.2) Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. Water flows to the lowest point it can. Put blocks over the water streams, and it will behave as you expect/want.

**More details on water:** Just like in real life, water tends to flow to the lowest available point. This includes joining with water streams or interacting with lava flows. In this case, the water is first flowing out to the three blocks immediately next to it, and those streams each attempt to flow to the nearest lower point. In this case, the one near the front flows right, as does the one on the right, but the one on the left flows left.

Answer (score 1):

Water is attracted to the nearest low point. Cover your sea lanterns with glass and between the pads and it should work as intended.